# How to work with for/in statement and fetch() in React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I'm working on a small `React` project that calls an `API`.

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {users: []};
}
```

`handleSubmit` is called when a user clicks on a button. The method then calls an `API`.

```
handleSubmit = (event) => {
    fetch(SERVER_URL + 'api/users')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(responseData => {
        this.setState({users: responseData._embedded.users,});

        // This is where I'm struggling.

        for(const respName in this.state.users.name){
            const allNames = respName; // Not working 
        };

    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

The `API` response in `JSON` looks like this:

```
{
  "_embedded": {
    "users": [
      {
        "name": "Tomes",
        "lastname": "River",
        "birthdate": "13/12/1994",
        "adress": "5 rue lolato STR",
        "phone": 1234567890,
        "email": "user@toto.fr",
        "password": "$2a$10$APhzDsJZ/qrz1BoyU3bRXO/OJ59KHQqduaExevABlxNJjud6X92VG",
        "role": "ADMIN",
      }
    ]
  },

    ....

}
```

I would like to retrieve the name of every user inside `users` in my `handleSubmit` method. I suppose it will be a `for/in` statement, but I'm unable to do it.

Comment: `users` is an Array, just iterate it like any other Array, `for(const user of users) {}`, `users.forEach(user => {})`, or whatever other iteration mechanism you'd like.  Please add an attempt to actually do the iteration, because right now your question is too broad.  We don't know what the problem actually is without a concrete attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is how to iterate over an array of json objects.
There are multiple ways to do it one way is to use `forEach()`:

```
.then(responseData => {
    let tempUsers=[];
    responseData._embedded.users.forEach((item)=>{
       tempUsers.push(item.name);
    })
    this.setState({users: tempUsers});

})
```